# Snapshot hell? Unable to free space on macOS Catalina

Tags: disk-space, apfs

Like many others I am unable to clear up space after deleting files.

I tried clearing snapshots:

```
# tmutil listlocalsnapshots /
Snapshots for volume group containing disk /:
# tmutil listlocalsnapshotdates /
Snapshot dates for volume group containing disk /:
# diskutil apfs listSnapshots /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD\ —\ Data
No snapshots for disk2s1
```

Space used according to `du`:

```
# pwd; du -schx *
/
151G    total
```

Disk file system usage

```
$ df -h /
Filesystem     Size   Used  Avail Capacity iused      ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk1s5  234Gi   10Gi   15Gi    41%  482081 2448643279    0%   /
```

I tried recovery mode and repairing the disk -

```
The volume Macintosh HD — Data was formatted by hfs_convert (748.1.47) and last modified by apfs_kext (1412.11.7)
Checking the object map
Checking the snapshot metadata tree
Checking the snapshot metadata
Checking snapshot 1 of 2 (com.apple.apfs.purgatory.274c46)
error: object (oid 0x19842b0): Bad size for physical extent record key, len: 9
Snapshot is invalid
The volume /dev/rdisk2s1 could not be verified completely
File system check exit code is 0
Restoring the original state found as unmounted
Finished file system verification on disk2s1 Macintosh HD — Data
```

Why do I have snapshot in 'purgatory'? How can I fix my disk? How can I free up the space?

Comment: You write that you've tried clearing local snapshots, but then only show 'list' commands.  Did you actually try clearing them?  E.g. `tmutil deletelocalsnapshots /`

Comment: @Redarm - Yes. Time machine snapshots have never caused me an issue in the past. They did take up space but that reduced after a triggering a backup. This issue hasn’t gone away since upgrading to Catalina.

Comment: Ending up restoring from TimeMachine. It initially failed, so I used DiskUtility to reformat and then restore and that seemed to work.